# Return size of singly linked list but can't use head

Tags: java

**so this is a give class which I can't change**

```java
public class MinList<E> {
    private SinglyLinkedNode<E> head = null;

    
    public void addFirst(E element) {
        SinglyLinkedNode<E> node = new SinglyLinkedNode<>();
        node.value = element;
        node.next = head;
        head = node;
    }

    public Minlist<E> tail() 
    {
        if (head == null) {
            throw new EmptyListException();
        }
        Minilist<E> list = new MinimalistList<>();
        list.head = head.next;
        return list;
    }

    public E getHeadValue() {
        return head.value;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return head == null;
    }
}
```

**here i have to implement `getSize()` to get size of singly linked list, but are not allowed to  change anything inside MinList ,so I can't use head ,because its private..**

```
public class MinListMain
 {
    public int getSize(MinList<Integer> list)
    {
      **// implement this Methode to get size of singlylinked list**
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MinList<Integer> intList = new MinList<>();
        intList.addFirst(1);
        intList.addFirst(2);
        intList.addFirst(3);
        MiniList main = new MiniListmain();
        System.out.println(main.getMinimum(intList));
        System.out.println(main.getSize(intList));
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between `MinList`, `Minilist`, and `MinimalistList`?

Answer (score 0):

Since `tail()` return a *new* list, with the tail after the head, i.e. a new list with the head "removed", you just keep calling `tail()` until the list is empty.

Given that it returns a new list, calling `tail()` leaves the original list unchanged.

So, in code, that means:

```java
public int getSize(MinList<Integer> list) {
    int size = 0;
    for (MinList<Integer> rest = list; ! rest.isEmpty(); rest = rest.tail()) {
        size++;
    }
    return size;
}
```

Comment: Thank you its really inspiring

Answer (score -1):

You could extend the class MinList and add a `count` attribute that you increment when `addFirst()` is called and decrement when `tail()` is called then you create a `getSize()`method in this new class that return `count`. That way you would have a class that does what you want with a `getSize()`method.

Comment: The exercise is to determine the size **without** modifying `MinList`, i.e. by *only* implementing the stub `getSize()` method shown in the question. --- Subclassing requires modifying code outside the `getSize()` method, i.e. the code in `main()`, so that's not an option.